# Want to restrict a part of my indicator to certain timeframes than other parts

Tags: pine-script, trading, tradingview-api, indicator

I was just making a combination of indicators i use - vwap, 50ema and imbalance.

I want it to show vwap only on 5minutes and below timeframes, whereas Ema on 15minutes and above.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do it in two ways, first one is to check if the timeframe is intraday and multiplier is 5 or less, like this:

```
vwap = ta.vwap(close)
ema_50 = ta.ema(close, 50)

plot(timeframe.isintraday and timeframe.multiplier <= 5 ? vwap: na, 
color=color.red)
plot(timeframe.isintraday and timeframe.multiplier <= 5 ? na: ema_50, 
color=color.yellow)
```

Second way is to specify an array of timeframes, here you have more flexibility

```
display_vwap_timeframe = array.new_string(3)
array.push(display_vwap_timeframe, "1")
array.push(display_vwap_timeframe, "3")
array.push(display_vwap_timeframe, "5")


plot(array.includes(display_vwap_timeframe, timeframe.period) ? vwap: na, color=color.red)
plot(array.includes(display_vwap_timeframe, timeframe.period) ? na: ema_50, color=color.yellow)
```

eventually you could even use two arrays of timeframes for vwap and ema 50, in this case you can just use an "if" clause (because when you show the vwap you don't want the ema 50)

**EDIT**

Code with the changing color as requested:

```
vwap = ta.vwap(close)
ema_50 = ta.ema(close, 50)

vwap_color = vwap > vwap[1] ? color.green : color.red
ema_color = ema_50 > ema_50[1] ? color.green : color.red

plot(timeframe.isintraday and timeframe.multiplier <= 5 ? vwap: na, color=vwap_color)
plot(timeframe.isintraday and timeframe.multiplier <= 5 ? na: ema_50, color=ema_color)
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply ! Actually i am very new to pine and coding in general , so i am getting syntax errors with these codes. I have my color changing vwap and ema codes with me, which change colors when price is above/below them. Can I send them? If you can please let me know your email or something..

Comment: Sure! you can send an email to matteobuffagni09@gmail.com or use discord and add Matb09#4388